# dplyr::select equivalent for subsetting a character vector

Tags: r, dplyr

Does anyone know whether there's the equivalent of `dplyr::select()` for subsetting character vectors? Specifically, what I like about `dplyr::select()` is the how easy it is to select dataframe columns; one can input the names of the columns (with or without quotes) and similarly create ranges from those names. Is there any function where you could take a character vector, and without using any helper function(s), create a range for the purposes of subsetting.

For example, let's create an aribitrary vector (but assume that this vector was the result of some other operation, like pulling sheet names from an Excel file):

```
char_vec <- c("Exclude1",
  paste0("Include", 1:5),
  "Exclude2")
```

Is there a function where a user could input: `someFunction(char_vec, Include1:Include5)` in order to get the result?

I realize that there are a bunch of regex related solutions as well as good old base R --  `char_vec[which(char_vec == "Include1"):which(char_vec == "Include5")]` -- but I was hoping for a function that resembled `dplyr::select()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have to go to base R. The functions of `dplyr` are useful for `data.frame` and `tibble` classes. But the moment you say your data is an atomic vector, `dplyr` (or `tidyverse`) doesn't work. This is because vector has only one column. So, there is no question of selecting columns. If you want to select rows from that column/vector using `dplyr`, you should convert it into `data.frame` (using `as.data.frame(df)`) or tibble (using `as_tibble(df)` function from `tibble` package), and then use `dplyr`'s filter verb.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that I was looking for a dplyr or even tidyverse solution, I was simply using dplyr's select() function to demonstrate the construction and functionality I was seeking; which could've originated from any package.

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky, but you could create a function that changes your character vector into dataframe column names, applies tidy selection helpers, then converts back to a character vector:

```
select_v <- function(x, ...) {
  x_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(x)))
  names(x_df) <- x
  names(dplyr::select(x_df, ...))
}

char_vec |>
  select_v(Include1:Include5)
# "Include1" "Include2" "Include3" "Include4" "Include5"

char_vec |>
  select_v(starts_with("Exc"), ends_with("4"))
# "Exclude1" "Exclude2" "Include4"
```

Note that, like `dplyr::select()`, this will throw an error if your selection includes any duplicate values (e.g., if `"Include2"` appeared twice in the vector).

Comment: Your final note is a good one. And yes, the solution is a bit too hacky -- though a hacky solution is better than none at all, so thanks are still in order. I was hoping someone would simply point me to a package or function I was unfamiliar with that had "out of the box" functionality similar to dplyr's select function. But it seems like that solution may not exist yet.